# realloc a struct pointer inner struct pointer in c

Tags: c

context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34528438/15603477

The original post left some realloc code unfinished in `read_solid`function, inside `if(strcmp("endfacet", line) == 0) {}`. trying to finish this part. but failed.
Almost the same as original post code.

Problem:
In `if((*sol)->nfacets == (*sol)->maxfacets) {}` code block, I need realloc a struct inner struct.
if I set FACETS = 3 then a single solid struct pointer can only hold 3 facet pointer. Now I want to resize/reallocated to make it can hold more facets pointers.

```
/*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522831/scanf-stops-working-abruptly/34528438#34528438
gcc \
-Wpointer-arith  -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels \
-Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wmissing-format-attribute  \
-Wcast-function-type -Wshadow=compatible-local \
-Wformat-security -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation \
array_struct96.c  &&./a.out dat/solid.txt
valgrind ./a.out  dat/solid.txt

*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<math.h>
/* constants - num dimensions, initial facets
 * allocated within each solid, and the max
 * chars per-line for fgets to read
 */
enum{NDIM = 3, FACETS = 3, MAXC= 256};
/* facets struct - declared as pointer member of 
 * struct solid allowing additional allocation to
 * hold as many normal/vertexes as required.
 */
typedef struct facet{
    double normal[NDIM];
    double vertex[NDIM][NDIM];
}facet;

/* struct solid holds the solid's name, 
 * a pointer to an array of stuct facet, 
 * the number of facets containing data, and 
 * the maximum presently allocated.
 */ 
typedef struct solid{
    char *name;
    facet *facets;
    size_t nfacets;
    size_t maxfacets;
}solid;
/* function prototypes */
solid *create_solid();
solid *read_solid(solid **sol, FILE *fp);
void print_solid(solid *sol);
void free_solid(solid *sol);
double xstrtod(char *str, char **ep);

/* simple allocate/initialize function
 * return must be assigned to pointer
 */
solid *create_solid()
{
    size_t i;
    solid *sol = calloc(1,sizeof *sol);
    sol->facets = calloc(FACETS, sizeof *(sol->facets));
    sol->nfacets = 0;
    sol->maxfacets = FACETS;
    for(i = 0; i < FACETS; i++){
        memset((sol->facets)[i].normal, 0,NDIM * sizeof(double));
        memset((sol->facets)[i].vertex, 0,NDIM * NDIM * sizeof(double));
    }
    return sol;
}

/*  simple print of normals & vertexes to stdout    */
void print_solid(solid *sol)
{
    if(!sol){
        fprintf(stderr,"printf_solid() error: invalid parameter 'sol'.\n");
        return;
    }
    size_t i,j;
    printf("Normal and vertexes for solid: %s\n", sol->name);
    printf("Total size of faces=%ld\n", sol->nfacets);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("record %ld: ", i+1);
        printf(
            "\nnormal[%3zu]:%10.4f\t%10.4f\t%10.4f\n",i
            ,sol->facets[i].normal[0]
            ,sol->facets[i].normal[1]
            ,sol->facets[i].normal[2]
        );
        for(j = 0; j < NDIM; j++)
            printf("vertex[%3zu]:%10.4f\t%10.4f\t%10.4f\n"
                ,j
                ,sol->facets[i].vertex[j][0]
                ,sol->facets[i].vertex[j][1]
                ,sol->facets[i].vertex[j][2]
            );
    }
}

void free_solid(solid *sol)
{
    if(sol->name) free(sol->name);
    if(sol->facets) free(sol->facets);
    if(sol) free(sol);
}

/* string to double with error checking. */
double xstrtod(char *str, char **ep)
{
    errno = 0;
    double val = strtod(str,ep);
    /* Check for various possible errors */
    if((errno == ERANGE  && (val == HUGE_VAL || val == HUGE_VALL)) ||
        (errno != 0 && val == 0)){
            perror("strtod");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(ep && *ep == str){
        fprintf(stderr,"No double were found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return val;    
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    solid *sol = NULL;  /* pointer to hold values */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (read_solid (&sol, fp)) {    /* read data from file  */
        print_solid (sol);          /* print data read      */
        free_solid (sol);           /* free all memory      */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close if not stdin   */

    return 0;
}

/* read_solid takes the poiner address for a struct solid,
 * and will read all normal and vertexes into the struct,
 * updating 'nfacets' with the number of facets for which
 * there is data, and will validate each read and conversion
 * of values from string to double. retuns filled struct on
 * success, NULL otherwise
 */
solid *read_solid(solid **sol, FILE *fp)
{
    char line[MAXC] = {0};  /*  temporary line buffer */
    size_t idx = 0, vidx = 0;   /* line & vertex indexes */
    if(!*sol) *sol = create_solid();     /* allocate & initialize struct */
    
    while(fgets(line,MAXC,fp))   /* read each line in file */
    {
        size_t len = 0;
        char *p, *ep;
        p = ep = line;
        len = strlen(line);  /* get length & remove '\n' */
        if(line[len - 1] == '\n')
            line[--len] = 0;

        if(!(ep = strchr(line,' ')))    /* test if space in line */
        {   /* if endfacet, update nfacets */
            if(strcmp("endfacet", line) == 0)
            {
                (*sol)->nfacets++;
                if((*sol)->nfacets == (*sol)->maxfacets)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr,"read_solid() warning: limit readed\n");
                    printf("(*sol)->nfacets=%ld\n", (*sol)->nfacets);
                    // sol->facets = calloc(FACETS, sizeof *(sol->facets));
                    printf("2 * ((*sol)->maxfacets:%ld\n",2 * (*sol)->maxfacets);

                    void *tmp = realloc ( (*sol)->facets, 2 * ( (*sol)->maxfacets ) * sizeof *(*sol)->facets);
                        if (!tmp) { /* if realloc fails, original pointer still valid */
                            perror ("realloc-sales");   /* throw error */
                            return (*sol);              /* return current pointer      */ 
                        }                               /* (don't exit or return NULL) */
                        (*sol)->facets = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to (*sol)->facets  */
                        /* (optional) zero newly allocated memory */
                        // memset ((*sol)->facets + (*sol)->nfacets, 0, ((*sol)->maxfacets) * sizeof *((*sol)->facets));
                    (*sol)->maxfacets *= 2;  /* update (*sol)->maxfacets to new size */
                    printf("this part do called\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            goto processed;
        }
        if(strncmp("solid",line,ep - p) == 0)
        {
            (*sol)->name = strdup(ep + 1);
            goto processed;
        }else if(strncmp("facet",line, ep - p) == 0)
        {
            size_t i;
            while(*ep &&(*ep < '0' || *ep > '9')) ep++; /* skip no digit value */
            if(!*ep){
                fprintf(stderr,"read_solid() error: facet normal no values\n");
                return NULL;
            }
            p = ep;
            for(i = 0; i < NDIM; i++){   /* convert to double & validate */
                /* for which sol index.
                for a specific index of sol
                then assign double to normal.*/
                (*sol)->facets[(*sol)->nfacets].normal[i] = xstrtod(p,&ep);
                p = ep;
            }
            goto processed;
        }else if(strncmp("vertex", line, ep - p) == 0)
        { /* read vertex values */
            size_t i;
            p = ep + 1;
            for(i = 0; i< NDIM; i++){/* convert to double & validate */
                (*sol)->facets[(*sol)->nfacets].vertex[vidx][i] = xstrtod(p,&ep);
                p = ep;
            }
            vidx = vidx < 2 ? vidx + 1 : 0; /* update/reset vertex index */
            goto processed;
        }else if(strncmp("outer",line,ep - p) == 0){ /* skip line begin with outer*/
            goto processed;
        }else if(strncmp("endsolid",line, ep - p) == 0){ /* skip line begin with endsolid*/
            goto processed;
        }else{
            fprintf(stderr,"read_solid() warning: invalid line at '%3zu'\n",idx);
        }
    processed:
        idx++;
    }
    
    if(!(*sol)->nfacets){
        fprintf(stderr,"read_solid() error: no data read.\n");
        free_solid(*sol);
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("idx=%ld\n", idx);
    return *sol;
}
```

---

In print_sold function. `for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)`  `0,1,2` is ok. but 3,4 print

```
record 4:
normal[  3]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
vertex[  0]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
vertex[  1]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
vertex[  2]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
record 5:
normal[  4]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
vertex[  0]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
vertex[  1]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
vertex[  2]:    0.0000      0.0000          0.0000
```

I modified `dat/solid.txt` file, so all print should be no zero value. Which mean the realloc part failed.

Comment: `if(sol) free(sol);` is nonsense; simply call `free(sol);`.

Comment: You could simplify your code considerably in `read_solid()` by using a local variable such as `solid *solp = (*sol != NULL) ? *sol : create_solid();` and then using `solp->facets` etc throughout the code (instead of `(*sol)->facets`), only reassigning `*sol = solp;` as the code exits the function.

Comment: You have a label `processed:` which lots of code in the `while (fgets(…))` loop jumps to.  Why not use a `for` loop: `for (idx = 0; fgets(…) != NULL; idx++)`, in which case, you no longer need the label at all (some `goto processed;` statements become `continue;` statements).  The `for` loop is not restricted to only simple counting loops (though this isn't far removed from a simple counting loop).

Comment: You should also use subfunctions in the I/O code — it's hard work reading a loop that won't fit onto a 65-line screen.  In your `if ((*sol)->nfacets == (*sol)->maxfacets)` , you have a `break;` after allocating more space.  That's surprising.  Why?

Comment: Also read [**Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).  Any code that references `line[strlen(line)-1]` will break if `line` happens to be an empty string `""`.  Use something like `line[strcspn(line,"\n")]='\0';`.  (And `line[strcspn(line,"\r\n")]='\0';` on Windows...)

Comment: The loop `for (i = 0; i < FACETS; i++) { memset((sol->facets)[i].normal, 0,NDIM * sizeof(double)); memset((sol->facets)[i].vertex, 0 ,NDIM * NDIM * sizeof(double)); }` redoes what the `calloc()` did — you don't need these calls to `memset()`.

Comment: Once you added the reallocation, you would need to remove the `break` to finish the loop. In the last example, `break` stopped processing when the limit was reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some heavily amended code that works without any obvious memory faults.

It has several major modifications, and umpteen minor ones (not all of which will be mentioned here):

- Using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop in `read_solid()`, which gets rid of the `processed` label.
- Using multiple subfunctions to make it easier to read the body of the processing loop.
- Since the `xstrtod()` function exits on error (in your code and this code), I've made the code "fail fast" in other places too.
- The code reading the 'normal' data no longer skips over `'+'` or `'-'` signs.
- The function `directive()` splits the line, isolating the directive from the data after it.  This makes it easier to write the list of comparisons, and the code can use `strcmp()` instead of `strncmp()`.
- There's a fairly simple `if` / `else if` / … / `else` chain in the loop, mostly just calling functions that do a task.
- I renamed the structure types with an initial capital (`Facet`, `Solid`).
- The `read_solid()` function is passed a pre-allocated `Solid` structure, which simplifies the code.
- Because the reading loop breaks when it encounters the `endsolid` line, it is possible for it to read multiple solids from a single file.

Code:

```c
/* SO 7456-2825 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { NDIM = 3, FACETS = 3, MAXC = 256 };

typedef struct Facet
{
    double normal[NDIM];
    double vertex[NDIM][NDIM];
} Facet;

typedef struct Solid
{
    char *name;
    Facet *facets;
    size_t nfacets;
    size_t maxfacets;
} Solid;

static Solid *create_solid(void);
static int read_solid(Solid *sol, FILE *fp);
static void print_solid(Solid *sol);
static void free_solid(Solid *sol);
static double xstrtod(char *str, char **ep);

static Solid *create_solid(void)
{
    Solid *sol;
    if ((sol = calloc(1, sizeof(*sol))) == NULL ||
        (sol->facets = calloc(FACETS, sizeof(sol->facets[0]))) == NULL)
    {
        free(sol);
        return NULL;
    }
    sol->nfacets = 0;
    sol->maxfacets = FACETS;
    return sol;
}

static void print_solid(Solid *sol)
{
    if (!sol)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s error: invalid parameter\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    printf("Normal and vertexes for solid: %s\n", sol->name);
    printf("Total size of faces=%zu\n", sol->nfacets);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sol->nfacets; i++)
    {
        printf("Facet %zu: ", i + 1);
        printf(
            "\nNormal[%3zu]:%10.4f\t%10.4f\t%10.4f\n", i,
            sol->facets[i].normal[0],
            sol->facets[i].normal[1],
            sol->facets[i].normal[2]
            );
        for (size_t j = 0; j < NDIM; j++)
        {
            printf("Vertex[%3zu]:%10.4f\t%10.4f\t%10.4f\n",
                   j,
                   sol->facets[i].vertex[j][0],
                   sol->facets[i].vertex[j][1],
                   sol->facets[i].vertex[j][2]
                   );
        }
    }
}

static void free_solid(Solid *sol)
{
    if (sol)
    {
        free(sol->name);
        free(sol->facets);
        free(sol);
    }
}

static double xstrtod(char *str, char **ep)
{
    errno = 0;
    double val = strtod(str, ep);

    if ((errno == ERANGE  && (val == HUGE_VAL || val == HUGE_VALL)) ||
        (errno != 0 && val == 0))
    {
        perror("strtod");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (ep && *ep == str)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No double were found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return val;
}

/* exits on failure */
static void more_facets(Solid *sol)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s() warning: limit reached (sol->nfacets = %zu)\n",
            __func__, sol->nfacets);

    size_t new_facets = 2 * sol->maxfacets;
    printf("new_facets = %zu\n", new_facets);

    void *tmp = realloc(sol->facets, new_facets * sizeof(sol->facets[0]));
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        perror(__func__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    sol->facets = tmp;
    sol->maxfacets = new_facets;
}

static void read_name(Solid *sol, char *name)
{
    sol->name = strdup(name);
    if (sol->name == NULL)
    {
        perror(__func__);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static void read_normal(Facet *fp, char *ep)
{
    while (*ep && !isdigit((unsigned char)*ep) && *ep != '+' && *ep != '-')
        ep++;
    if (!*ep)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(): error: facet normal no values\n", __func__);
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NDIM; i++)
    {
        char *p = ep;
        fp->normal[i] = xstrtod(p, &ep);
    }
}

static void read_vertex(Facet *facet, char *ep, size_t vidx)
{
    assert(vidx < NDIM);
    char *p = ep;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NDIM; i++)
    {
        facet->vertex[vidx][i] = xstrtod(p, &ep);
        p = ep;
    }
}

/* Isolate directive into null-terminated string */
/* Return pointer to data after blank after directive, or null byte */
static char *directive(char *line)
{
    char *ep = strchr(line, ' ');
    if (ep != NULL)
        *ep++ = '\0';
    else
        ep += strlen(line);
    return ep;
}

/*
** Note that the scanning does not enforce the correct sequencing of
** facet, outer, vertex, vertex, vertex, endloop, endfacet
** There are other infelicities that are not detected.
*/
static int read_solid(Solid *sol, FILE *fp)
{
    char line[MAXC];
    size_t vidx = 0;

    for (size_t lineno = 0; fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL; lineno++)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        char *ep = directive(line);

        if (strcmp("endfacet", line) == 0)
            continue;
        else if (strcmp("endloop", line) == 0)
            continue;
        else if (strcmp("outer", line) == 0)
            vidx = 0;
        else if (strcmp("endsolid", line) == 0)
            break;
        else if (strcmp("solid", line) == 0)
            read_name(sol, ep);
        else if (strcmp("facet", line) == 0)
        {
            assert(sol->nfacets <= sol->maxfacets);
            if (sol->nfacets == sol->maxfacets)
                more_facets(sol);
            read_normal(&sol->facets[sol->nfacets++], ep);
        }
        else if (strcmp("vertex", line) == 0)
            read_vertex(&sol->facets[sol->nfacets - 1], ep, vidx++);
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s() warning: invalid directive '%s' at '%3zu' ignored\n",
                    __func__, line, lineno);
        }
    }

    if (!sol->nfacets)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "read_solid() error: no data read.\n");
        free_solid(sol);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("idx=%zu\n", sol->nfacets);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error: file open failed '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    Solid *sol = create_solid();
    if (sol == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error: failed to create solid\n", argv[0]);
    }

    if (read_solid(sol, fp) == 0)
    {
        print_solid(sol);
        free_solid(sol);
    }
    if (fp != stdin)
        fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

When run on the full-size (24-facet) data file from the prior question, it produces the output:

```
more_facets() warning: limit reached (sol->nfacets = 3)
more_facets() warning: limit reached (sol->nfacets = 6)
more_facets() warning: limit reached (sol->nfacets = 12)
new_facets = 6
new_facets = 12
new_facets = 24
idx=24
Normal and vertexes for solid: Untitled-56807ca1
Total size of faces=24
Facet 1: 
Normal[  0]:    0.0000      0.0000     -1.0000
Vertex[  0]:  100.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  1]:    0.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  2]:    0.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Facet 2: 
Normal[  1]:    0.0000      0.0000     -1.0000
Vertex[  0]:    0.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  1]:  100.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  2]:  100.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Facet 3: 
Normal[  2]:   -1.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  0]:    0.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:    0.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  2]:    0.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Facet 4: 
Normal[  3]:   -1.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  0]:    0.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  1]:    0.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:    0.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Facet 5: 
Normal[  4]:   -0.0000      1.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  0]:    0.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:  100.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  2]:    0.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Facet 6: 
Normal[  5]:   -0.0000      1.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  0]:  100.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  1]:    0.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:  100.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Facet 7: 
Normal[  6]:    1.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  0]:  100.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  1]:  100.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:  100.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Facet 8: 
Normal[  7]:    1.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  0]:  100.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:  100.0000     50.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  2]:  100.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Facet 9: 
Normal[  8]:   -0.0000     -1.0000     -0.0000
Vertex[  0]:  100.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:    0.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  2]:  100.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Facet 10: 
Normal[  9]:   -0.0000     -1.0000     -0.0000
Vertex[  0]:    0.0000      0.0000      0.0000
Vertex[  1]:  100.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:    0.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Facet 11: 
Normal[ 10]:    0.8394      0.0000      0.5436
Vertex[  0]:  100.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:  100.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Facet 12: 
Normal[ 11]:    0.8394      0.0000      0.5436
Vertex[  0]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  1]:  100.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:   69.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Facet 13: 
Normal[ 12]:   -0.8394     -0.0000      0.5436
Vertex[  0]:   31.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  1]:    0.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:    0.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Facet 14: 
Normal[ 13]:   -0.8394     -0.0000      0.5436
Vertex[  0]:    0.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:   31.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   31.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Facet 15: 
Normal[ 14]:   -0.0000     -0.9514      0.3081
Vertex[  0]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  1]:    0.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:  100.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Facet 16: 
Normal[ 15]:   -0.0000     -0.9514      0.3081
Vertex[  0]:    0.0000      0.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   31.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Facet 17: 
Normal[ 16]:    0.0000      0.9514      0.3081
Vertex[  0]:   31.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  1]:  100.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  2]:    0.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Facet 18: 
Normal[ 17]:    0.0000      0.9514      0.3081
Vertex[  0]:  100.0000     50.0000     67.8050
Vertex[  1]:   31.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   69.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Facet 19: 
Normal[ 18]:    0.0000     -0.8820      0.4713
Vertex[  0]:   50.0000     25.0000    133.4520
Vertex[  1]:   31.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Facet 20: 
Normal[ 19]:    0.6832      0.0000      0.7302
Vertex[  0]:   69.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  1]:   50.0000     25.0000    133.4520
Vertex[  2]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Facet 21: 
Normal[ 20]:   -0.6832      0.0000      0.7302
Vertex[  0]:   50.0000     25.0000    133.4520
Vertex[  1]:   31.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   31.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Facet 22: 
Normal[ 21]:   -0.0000     -0.0000      1.0000
Vertex[  0]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  1]:   31.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   31.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Facet 23: 
Normal[ 22]:   -0.0000     -0.0000      1.0000
Vertex[  0]:   31.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  1]:   69.0000     15.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   69.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Facet 24: 
Normal[ 23]:   -0.0000      0.8820      0.4713
Vertex[  0]:   50.0000     25.0000    133.4520
Vertex[  1]:   69.0000     34.5000    115.6740
Vertex[  2]:   31.0000     34.5000    115.6740
```

I think that the break you have in the code after allocating more facets was the main cause of your trouble.

If I were working on it further, I'd have a code structure that insisted on the correct sequencing.  With the functions in place, it is fairly easy to see how to do this.  This would eliminate the `vidx` in the main loop, which is still pretty ugly.  I'd also consider making a structure type for the 3 numbers (`struct Point { double x; double y; double z; };` or `struct Point { double value[3]; };` or similar, and using that in the `Facet` structure.  It would simplify the argument handling.